# Swift 5 - Email Class Helper / Manager

Tags: ios, swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, class-hierarchy, messageui

### Edit:

Big thanks to Paulw11 for helping me solve this issue. I've added the full code here for easy reuse:

Class:

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI

struct Feedback {
    let recipients: [String]
    let subject: String
    let body: String
    let footer: String
}

class FeedbackManager: NSObject, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

private var feedback: Feedback

private var completion: ((Result<MFMailComposeResult,Error>)->Void)?

override init() {
    fatalError("Use FeedbackManager(feedback:)")
}

init?(feedback: Feedback) {
    guard MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() else {
        return nil
    }
    
    self.feedback = feedback
}

func send(on viewController: UIViewController, completion:(@escaping(Result<MFMailComposeResult,Error>)->Void)) {
    
    let mailVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    self.completion = completion
    
    mailVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
    mailVC.setToRecipients(feedback.recipients)
    mailVC.setSubject(feedback.subject)
    mailVC.setMessageBody("<p>\(feedback.body)<br><br><br><br><br>\(feedback.footer)</p>", isHTML: true)
    
    viewController.present(mailVC, animated:true)
}

func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
    if let error = error {
        completion?(.failure(error))
        controller.dismiss(animated: true)
    } else {
        completion?(.success(result))
        controller.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
}
```

In View Controller:

Add Variable:

```
var feedbackManager: FeedbackManager?
```

Use:

```
    let feedback = Feedback(recipients: "String", subject: "String", body: "Body", footer: "String")
    if let feedManager = FeedbackManager(feedback: feedback) {
        self.feedbackManager = feedManager
        self.feedbackManager?.send(on: self) { [weak self] result in
            switch result {
            case .failure(let error):
                print("error: ", error.localizedDescription)
            // Do something with the error
            case .success(let mailResult):
                print("Success")
                // Do something with the result
            }
            self?.feedbackManager = nil
        }
    } else { // Cant Send Email: // Added UI Alert:
        let failedMenu = UIAlertController(title: "String", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAlert = UIAlertAction(title: "String", style: .default)
        failedMenu.addAction(okAlert)
        present(failedMenu, animated: true)
    }
```

---

I'm trying to make a class that handles initializing a MFMailComposeViewController to send an email inside of the app.

I'm having issues making it work. Well, rather making it not crash if it *doesn't* work.

class:

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI

struct Feedback {
    let recipients = "String"
    let subject: String
    let body: String
}

class FeedbackManager: MFMailComposeViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
    
    func sendEmail(feedback: Feedback) {
        
        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            
            self.mailComposeDelegate = self
            self.setToRecipients([feedback.recipients])
            self.setSubject("Feedback: \(feedback.subject)")
            self.setMessageBody("<p>\(feedback.body)</p>", isHTML: true)
            
        } else {
            print("else:")
            mailFailed()
        }
    }
    
    func mailFailed() {
        print("mailFailed():")
        let failedMenu = UIAlertController(title: "Please Email Me!", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAlert = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok!", style: .default)
        failedMenu.addAction(okAlert)
        self.present(failedMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

And then calling it from a different view controller:

```
  let feedbackManager = FeedbackManager()
  feedbackManager.sendEmail(feedback: Feedback(subject: "String", body: "String"))
  self.present(feedbackManager, animated: true, completion: nil)
  tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
```

The above works just fine if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() == true. The problem I'm facing is that if canSendMail() is not true, then the class obviously cant initialize and crashes. Which makes sense.

Error:

```
Unable to initialize due to + [MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail] returns NO.
```

I'm not sure where to go from here on how to get this working. I've tried changing FeedbackManager from MFMailComposeViewController to a UIViewController. And that seems to work but because it's adding a view on the stack, it's causing a weird graphical display.

The other thing I could do is import MessageUI, and conform to MFMailComposeViewController for every controller I want to be able to send an email from. So that I can check against canSendMail() before trying to initialize FeedbackManager(). But that also doesn't seem like the best answer.

How else can I get this working?

EDIT:
I've gotten the code to work with this however, there is an ugly transition with the addition of the view onto the stack before it presents the MFMailComposeViewController.

```
class FeedbackManager: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
    
    func sendEmail(feedback: Feedback, presentingViewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController {
        
        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            
            let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
            mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
            mail.setToRecipients([feedback.recipients])
            mail.setSubject("Feedback: \(feedback.subject)")
            mail.setMessageBody("<p>\(feedback.body)</p>", isHTML: true)
            
             present(mail, animated: true)
            return self
        } else {
            print("else:")
            return mailFailed(presentingViewController: presentingViewController)
        }
    }
    
    func mailFailed(presentingViewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController {
        print("mailFailed():")
        let failedMenu = UIAlertController(title: "Please Email Me!", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAlert = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok!", style: .default)
        failedMenu.addAction(okAlert)
        return failedMenu
    }
    
    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true)
        self.dismiss(animated: false)
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown the initialiser for your class, which is where I presume that message is coming from, but I would suggest you make it a failable initialiser and handle the failure as you need to,or you could have `sendEmail` return `false`. Either way, trying to to throw up an alert from inside `FeedbackManager`isn't the right approach

Comment: Hey Paul, I think i initialized it? in a different view control With let feedbackManager = FeedbackManager(). You are correct that presenting the alert in this class is the wrong way to do it. I’ve tried a number of approaches of all sorts of things including returning the UIViewControllers to the presenting controller. But no matter what I try, I can get one to work just fine. But not both.

Comment: @Paulw11 - After rereading your comment, the error is a result of the class being a subclass of MFMailComposeViewController and not UIViewController. My issue is that the class works to send emails if it MFMailComposeViewController. But in by doing so, if canSendMail = false, it crashes. - If I instead use UIViewController, it fails without crashing, it presents the MFMailComposeViewController view, but the delegate doesn't register so sending/canceling does not dismiss the view.

Comment: Your problem is that you are subclassing `MFMailViewComposeViewController`; You should not subclass that class. It is intended to be used as-is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Subclassing `MFMailComposeViewController` is the wrong approach.  This class is intended to be used "as-is".  You can build a wrapper class if you like:

```
struct Feedback {
    let recipients = "String"
    let subject: String
    let body: String
}

class FeedbackManager: NSObject, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
    
    private var feedback: Feedback
    
    private var completion: ((Result<MFMailComposeResult,Error>)->Void)?
    
    override init() {
        fatalError("Use FeedbackManager(feedback:)")
    }
    
    init?(feedback: Feedback) {
        guard MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() else {
            return nil
        }
        
        self.feedback = feedback
    }
    
    func send(on viewController: UIViewController, completion:(@escaping(Result<MFMailComposeResult,Error>)->Void)) {
        
        let mailVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        self.completion = completion
        
        mailVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
        mailVC.setToRecipients([feedback.recipients])
        mailVC.setSubject("Feedback: \(feedback.subject)")
        mailVC.setMessageBody("<p>\(feedback.body)</p>", isHTML: true)
        
        viewController.present(mailVC, animated:true)
    } 
    
    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
        if let error = error {
            completion?(.failure(error))
        } else {
            completion?(.success(result))
        }
    }
}
```

And then to use it from a view controller:

```
let feedback = Feedback(subject: "String", body: "Body")
if let feedbackMgr = FeedbackManager(feedback: feedback) {
    self.feedbackManager = feedbackMgr
    feedback.send(on: self) { [weak self], result in 
        switch result {
            case .failure(let error):
                // Do something with the error
            case .success(let mailResult):
                // Do something with the result
        }
        self.feedbackManager = nil
    }
} else {
    // Can't send email
}
```

You will need to hold a strong reference to the `FeedbackManager` in a property otherwise it will be released as soon as the containing function exits.  My code above refers to a property

```
var feedbackManager: FeedbackManager?
```

While this will work, a better UX is if you check `canSendMail` directly and disable/hide the UI component that allows them to send feedback

Comment: Hey Paul, Thank you for the reply. I gave it a try. Everything other than the mailComposeController delegate seems to be working. - I don't understand what a wrapper is. (Actually just read about them earlier today for the first time. So It's on tomorrows learning list) But is the delegate working for you?

Comment: I've done some testing by putting print statements at the top of each method and it doesn't appear that the delegate method doesn't ever gets called. - This is the same issue I've been having. And it's why I subclassed MFMailComposeViewController in the other answer. Because setting self.mailComposeDelegate = self and then presenting self was the only I was I was able to figure out how to get both the view with the delegate. I can't figure out how to get the delegate function to fire correctly.

Comment: Hey Paul, Thanks for the update. I got it working! Thank you! :)

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for putting this together. The delegate didFinish doesn't seem to work for me when I call it from a UIAlertViewController, any ideas?  I am also passing the parent vc of the alertvc.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the code as follows.

```
struct Feedback {
    let recipients = "String"
    let subject: String
    let body: String
}

class FeedbackManager: NSObject, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
    
    func sendEmail(presentingViewController: UIViewController)) {
        
        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            
            let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
            mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
            mail.setToRecipients([feedback.recipients])
            mail.setSubject("Feedback: \(feedback.subject)")
            mail.setMessageBody("<p>\(feedback.body)</p>", isHTML: true)
            presentingViewController.present(mail, animated: true)
            
        } else {
            print("else:")
            mailFailed(presentingViewController: presentingViewController)
        }
    }
    
    func mailFailed(presentingViewController: UIViewController) {
        print("mailFailed():")
        let failedMenu = UIAlertController(title: "Please Email Me!", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAlert = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok!", style: .default)
        failedMenu.addAction(okAlert)
        presentingViewController.present(failedMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Now, mailComposer can be opened as follows from another `UIViewController` class.

```
let feedbackManager = FeedbackManager()
feedbackManager.sendEmail(presentingViewController: self)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thats what I'm trying to achieve. However the issue I'm running into is that if the class is set as above, then it crashes if canSendMail = false. But setting the subclass to UIViewController allows the return of the UIAlertController correctly. And presents MFMailComposeViewController. But the delegate is not set. so while it will send an email, the view doesn't dismiss.

Comment: I am using the above code in my project. It works without any crashes. For dismissal not working, please see that feedback manager instance is actually an instance variable rather than local variable.

Comment: The exact code above does not work for me. - I have it code directly and it presents an error. *Cannot declare conformance to 'NSObjectProtocol' in Swift; 'FeedbackManager' should inherit 'NSObject' instead*. - Subclassing to UIViewController fixes it. However, it still crashes if canSendMail = false and the delegate protocols are not working.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by first adding a class that checks if .canSendMail is true. If it is, it then taps into the postal sending class to present the MFMailComposeViewController.

This is the only workaround I've come up with that allows MFMailComposeViewController to be it's own MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate. While also preventing a crash if .canSendMail = false.

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI

struct Feedback {
    let recipients = ["Strings"]
    let subject: String
    let body: String
}

class FeedbackManager {

    func tryMail() -> Bool {
        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }

    func mailFailed() -> UIViewController {
        let failedMenu = UIAlertController(title: "Please Email Me!", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAlert = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok!", style: .default)
        failedMenu.addAction(okAlert)
        return failedMenu
    }
}

class PostalManager: MFMailComposeViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

    func sendEmail(feedback: Feedback) -> MFMailComposeViewController {
        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            self.mailComposeDelegate = self
            self.setToRecipients(feedback.recipients)
            self.setSubject("Feedback: \(feedback.subject)")
            self.setMessageBody("<p>\(feedback.body)</p>", isHTML: true)
        }
        return self
    }

    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Called with:

```
let feedbackManager = FeedbackManager()
let feedback = Feedback(subject: "String", body: "Body")

switch feedbackManager.tryMail() {

case true:
let postalManager = PostalManager()
present(postalManager.sendEmail(feedback: feedback), animated: true)
case false:
present(feedbackManager.mailFailed(), animated: true)
}
```